# static, hover, click, mouseout when you click on something else

Tags: javascript, onclick, hover, mouseover, mouseout

i am designing a timeline where when you hover over an image, it changes to another image, and when you click on it, it changes to yet another image. then when you click on a different portion of the timeline, it turns off what you just had clicked on. can anyone help me with this?

Here is what i have so far.

HTML:

```
<div class="all-bullets">
    <div class="bulletPlayer">
        <a class="bulletOne"></a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="bulletPlayer">
        <a class="bulletTwo"></a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="bulletPlayer">
        <a class="bulletThree"></a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="bulletPlayer">
        <a class="bulletFour"></a><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.all-bullets {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 492px;
margin-left: -41px;
margin-top: 140px;
}
.bulletPlayer {
position: relative;
z-index: 9999;
}



/* BULLET ONE*/
.bulletOne {
display: inline-block;
width: 500px;
height: 126px;
background: url(images/dotOneUpState.png) no-repeat left top;
}

.bulletOne:hover 
{
background: url(images/dotOneHoverState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -5px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.bulletOne.active 
{
background: url(images/dotOneDownState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -5px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}



/* BULLET TWO*/
.bulletTwo {
display: inline-block;
width: 500px;
height: 126px;
background: url(images/dotTwoUpState.png) no-repeat left top;
}

.bulletTwo:hover 
{
background: url(images/dotTwoHoverState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -3px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.bulletTwo.active 
{
background: url(images/dotTwoDownState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -3px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}




/* BULLET THREE*/

.bulletThree {
display: inline-block;
width: 500px;
height: 126px;
background: url(images/dotThreeUpState.png) no-repeat left top;
}

.bulletThree:hover 
{
background: url(images/dotThreeHoverState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -4px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.bulletThree.active 
{
background: url(images/dotThreeDownState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -4px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}


/* BULLET FOUR*/
.bulletFour {
display: inline-block;
width: 500px;
height: 123px;
background: url(images/dotFourUpState.png) no-repeat left top;
cursor: pointer;
}

.bulletFour:hover 
{
background: url(images/dotFourHoverState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -3px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.bulletFour.active 
{
background: url(images/dotFourDownState.png) no-repeat left top;
margin-left: -3px;
margin-top: -3px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.bulletOne').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active')
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active')
}
```

});

```
$('.bulletTwo').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active')
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active')
}
});

$('.bulletThree').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active')
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active')
}
});

$('.bulletFour').click(function(){
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active')
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active')
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried *anything* or do you want us to spoonfeed you?

Comment: Excuse me but I am on here to get feedback from knowledgable people, not rude answers. I am still learning and I am extremely new to all of this and have been researching and trying stuff on JS fiddle all day. i would be happy to show you what i have so far if you are willing to help and not be so passive aggressive

Comment: I'm willing to help with people who show effort and proactively help to get an answer. If you've tried something, great, then show us so we can assist you. When you show no effort it gives us the feeling that you've done nothing and you just want to be fed the answer, with no effort. No one is obligated to help anyone here and everyone is here at their own expense.

Comment: Andrew, I have updated my comments section with what i have so far that is closest to what i need. currently, there is a static state image, a hover state image, and an click image. there are 4 bullets with this exact set up. I would like for when i click on another bullet for it to turn off the previous bullet. let me know if you understand what i mean.

Comment: Do you have any specific questions? This is quite broad. Are there any errors, problems, etc?

Comment: im having trouble trying to figure out how to make the bullet disappear when i click on another bullet. currently i can click on a bullet and they all stay on. i want to just have one showing at all times. its not showing errors.

I can click it on and click it off. but i just want it to turn off on its own when i click on another bullet.

Comment: unfortunately it isnt showing up in either of those programs, however i can show you the site i have so far:

http://assets.daddario.com/landing_calftone/calftone_landing.html

its the top timeline section with the bullets.

Comment: I'd like to refrain from long discussion in comments, so we can continue this conversation in chat:

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115553/room-for-andrew-emily

Comment: unfortunately my reputation isnt high enough yet for that, im sorry

Comment: i saw that my rep went up and it said i need 20, i keep refreshing the page, then clearing my history and for some reason still not working. gonna restart my chrome thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115555/discussion-between-emily-kendall-shortell-and-andrew-l).

Comment: Hey Andrew, unfortunately it said that i have a reputation on stack overflow of 21 ut a reputation of 16 on stack overflow meta and wont let me chat. i appreciate you trying to help, but unfortunately i cant use that feature yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the list and disable those that aren't supposed to be active. Try this:

```
$(".bullet").click(function() { //Click function
    var selBullet = $(this), //Selected button
        bullets = document.getElementsByClassName("bullet"); //bullets nodeList
    selBullet.addClass("activeBullet"); //adding activeBullet class
    for(var i = bullets.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) { //iterate through all
        if(!selBullet.is($(bullets[i]))) { //check if same as selected
            $(bullets[i]).removeClass("activeBullet"); //if not, remove class
        }
    }
});
```

This will iterate through the nodeList of all bullets, then will remove active classes on the bullets that shouldn't be active. Here is a snippet:

```js
$(".bullet").click(function() {
    var selBullet = $(this),
     bullets = document.getElementsByClassName("bullet");
    selBullet.addClass("activeBullet");
    for(var i = bullets.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(!selBullet.is($(bullets[i]))) {
           $(bullets[i]).removeClass("activeBullet");
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.bullet {
  color: red;
}

.activeBullet {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="b">
    <a class="bullet activeBullet">Test_1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <a class="bullet">Test_2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <a class="bullet">Test_3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```